# Set previously selected value in dropdown if return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 dropdowns. One is minimum size and another one is maximum size. I am checking if selected value from minimum select box is greater than the selected value of maximum select box and vice versa. It works well.

I am stuck at one place where I want to set the previous value as 'selected' if the validation returns false. It doesn't let me to do that.

The demo is here -- https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/2fnxw609/1/

JS code

```
 $("select[name=size-min],select[name=size-max]").focus(function() {
   // Store the current value on focus, before it changes
   previous = this.value;
 }).change(function() {

   var selname = $(this).attr('name');
   var selval = $(this).val();
   var e1 = document.getElementById("size-min");
   var minval = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
   var e2 = document.getElementById("size-max");
   var maxval = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;

   alert(previous);

   if (selname == "size-min" && parseInt(minval) > parseInt(maxval) && maxval != "") {
     $('#size-min').val(previous);
     alert("The minimum size needs to be smaller than maximum size.");
     return false;
   }
   if (selname == "size-max" && parseInt(selval) < parseInt(minval)) {
     $('#size-max').val(previous);
     alert("The maximum size needs to be greater than minimum size.");
     return false;
   }

 });
```

Is it at all possible what I am trying to achieve. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your demo seems to work. If my _min_ value is greater than the _max_ one, my _min_ `<select>` change to the old value.

Comment: It doesn't change. That's the problem.

Comment: Try replacing the `.focus()` event with `.click()`

Comment: Try with Chrome, it does. The issue is with Firefox

Comment: I believe your code works for me as well, but what do you mean by "it doesn't change?".  It sounds like it's not supposed to change.  (In both fire-fox and chrome)

Comment: @KoCour Brilliant. It works with .click.

Comment: @Robiseb yes true. Any specific reason. .click() works in both browser but not .focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer: but demonstrating that your logic is sound (and perhaps taking more advantage of jQuery features)

```js
function init() {
  var previous;
 $(".minmax").focus(function() {
   // Store the current value on focus, before it changes
   previous = this.value;
 }).change(function(e) {
   if (parseInt($("#size-max").val()) < parseInt($("#size-min").val())) {
     $(this).val(previous);
     console.log($(this).attr('id')=="size-min"?"The minimum size needs to be smaller than maximum size.":"The maximum size needs to be greater than minimum size.");
   }
   previous = this.value; // Chrome calls "change" every time the value changes.  Firefox only calls it when the element loses focus.  This change makes chromes behavior a little more intuitive
 });
}
$(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form>
<select class="minmax" id="size-min">
  <option selected>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
<select class="minmax" id="size-max">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option selected>5</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: This solution is nice but doesn't explain what OP's code misbehaved across browsers

Comment: @KoCour you're incorrect about what's going on with firefox.

Comment: @Tibrogargan So what really happens there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at on Firefox `.focus()` does not trigger if the input is already focused - for example when you are correcting our option on the same combobox - the `previous` won't change because it was already focused.

Your code should work when `.focus()` event is replaced with `.click()`.

Therefore before selecting the new option, the previous one gets always saved no matter if that particular combobox was already focused or not.

Comment: This will fail if the user focuses on the `select` without clicking on it